# Calculation for inter-rater reliability where raters don't overlap and different number per candidate?

Tags: stata, reliability, agreement-statistics

I want to calculate the degree to which the gymnastics judges agree on balance beam scores, i.e., "inter-rater reliability". However, not all judges judge the same candidates, and the number of judges per candidate also varies. There are around 30 judges making roughly 1500 observations.

The data looks like this:

[image]

Can you please tell me how to do this statistically, perhaps using Cronbach's alpha?

STATA set-up advice would help, as well.

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are off topic here, but you may have 
a real statistical question buried here. You may want to edit your question to 
clarify the underlying statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using the [kappa-statistic measure](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rkappa.pdf) of interrater agreement. Before proceeding, we will need to reshape the data so that each row is a gymnast  but each score variable corresponds to single judge.

```
clear
input byte Gymnast str9 Judge double Score
1 Smith 5.5
1 Bartlet 6
1 Baily 8
2 Smith 10
2 Patterson 9.5
3 Baily 8
3 Patterson 7
3 Smith 7.5 
4 Bartlet 7.5
end
rename Score Score_
reshape wide Score_, i(Gymnast) j(Judge, string)
kap Score_*
```

The combined kappa is -0.1912, which would be considered poor. Stata recommends the following RoTs for summarizing agreement:

```
below 0.0 Poor
0.00 – 0.20 Slight
0.21 – 0.40 Fair
0.41 – 0.60 Moderate
0.61 – 0.80 Substantial
0.81 – 1.00 Almost perfect
```

Comment: If I do that, I get:  "Judge not unique within Gymnast;
there are multiple observations at the same Judge within Gymnast." I'm not sure what that means except I think it's because not all Gymnasts have the same set of Judges....

Comment: It's probably not that since in my example the set of judges varies across gymnasts and it works. Before you reshape, try `duplicates tag Gymnast Judge, gen(dups)` and `tab dups`. If dups is ever above zero, you have the same gymnast judged twice by the same judge. This could happen if the gymnast competes in two separate competitions. If that is the case, you have panel data, which is harder to model and will require some  additional assumptions before you can proceed.

Comment: Maybe I have 2 duplicates? In which case, perhaps I can just drop those points?   

    `Dups    Freq            Percent        Cum1`
    `0             1140         99.82           99.82`  
    `1              2                0.18            100`  
    `Total      1142   100.00`

Comment: Looks like you have 2 duplicates. It might well be a data entry error, so take a look at the scores. They might be the same, so you can just drop one of the rows. If not, you have to use your judgment.

Comment: I went ahead and dropped the row. But now I get:                                          "kap Score* matsize too small. You have attempted to create a matrix with too many rows or columns or attempted to fit a model with too many variables.  You need  to increase matsize; it is currently 800...."

Comment: I can't replicate your error, but this can probably be fixed with `set matsize XXX`, where XXX is some suitably large integer like 1500.

Comment: @EconoQ Did this help?

Comment: Yes, this helped. My STATA version isn't powerful enough to finish the calculation, but your advice did help. As it turns out, I think I'll have to calculate inter-rater reliability in blocks of gymnasts with the same judges.... and then the average difference between judges in each block should correlated to the average difference between judges of the other blocks (even if one block of gymnasts scores significantly less than the others). Then, I could also enter all gymnasts of a single block into a regression with the judges to make sure there's no correlation...right?

Comment: @EconoQ I am not sure what you want to accomplish, so I cannot help here. I might ask this question on Statalist with the added constraint about Stata version.